# cakephp 2.8 vs 1.3 smtp difference which would cause a 550 error

Tags: cakephp

We've recently updated an application from Cakephp 1.3 to version 2.8.

We use the application to send order information email messages to customers via a separate SMTP server. There can be as many as 1,000 messages sent at one time.

Our 1.3 application used to bulk send happily without ever incurring a 550 Maximum recipient quota exceeded message, even for volumes that exceeded the maximum recipient level on the SMTP server. The SMTP server has not changed. The max recipients level is set to 500 per hour, as it always has been.

Cakephp version 2 has a new method of dealing with email (CakeEmail):
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

There must be a fundamental difference in the ways that Cakephp 1.3 and Cakephp 2.8 sends email via an SMTP method, but I'm really struggling to see it. Can anyone help please?

Relevant code is shown below

/// 1.3 Code

```
$config['smtp'] = array(
        'port'=>'25',
        'timeout'=>'30',
        'host' => 'mail.smtpservername.com',
        'username'=>'smtp@domainname.com',
        'password'=>'password'
);


private function send_email($customer, $email_message) {

        $this->Email->from = 'Sender Name <address@domain.com>';
        $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
            'port'=>Configure::read('smtp.port'),
            'timeout'=>Configure::read('smtp.timeout'),
            'host' => Configure::read('smtp.host'),
            'username'=>Configure::read('smtp.username'),
            'password'=>Configure::read('smtp.password')
        );

        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
        $this->Email->to = $customer['first_name'].' '.$customer['last_name'].' <'.$customer['email_address'].'>';
        $this->Email->subject = 'A nice subject line';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'text';
        $this->Email->template = 'simple_message';
        $this->set('email_content', $email_message);

        if (!$this->Email->send()) {
            CakeLog::write('error', "Sending email to customer {$customer['id']} failed.");
            throw new EmailNotSentException("Sending email to customer {$customer['id']} failed.\n\n".$email_message);
        }

        $this->Email->reset();
        return true;
    }
```

/// 2.8 Code

```
$config['smtp'] = array(
    'port'      => '25',
    'timeout'   => '30',
    'host'      => 'mail.smtpservername.com',
    'username'  => 'smtp@domainname.com',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);

private function send_email($customer, $email_message)
    {
        $Email = new CakeEmail;
        $Email->config(Configure::read('smtp'));

        $from = array('address@domain.com' => 'Sender Name');
        $recipient = array($customer['email_address'] => $customer['first_name'] . ' ' . $customer['last_name']);
        $subject = 'A nice subject line';

        $Email->from($from);
        $Email->to($recipient);
        $Email->subject($subject);
        $Email->emailFormat('text');
        $Email->template('simple_message');
        $Email->viewVars(array('email_content' => $email_message));

        if (! $Email->send()) {
            CakeLog::write('error', "Sending email to customer {$customer['id']} failed.");
            throw new EmailNotSentException("Sending email to customer {$customer['id']} failed.\n\n".$email_message);
        }

        $Email->reset();
        return true;
    }
```